# How to update UIButton in navbar rightItem each time when it is taped in UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

I created button for navbar with custom image and want to change its tint color each time user taps on it.

```
 let addToFavoritesButton = UIImage(systemName: SystemImages.FilledStar.rawValue)
 navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: addToFavoritesButton, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addOrRemoveFromFavorites))
 navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = presenter.addToFavoriteButtonColor()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this the change of the rightBarButtonItem tint color inside the function you created for the tap on the rightBarButtonItem

```
   @objc func addOrRemoveFromFavorites(_ sender: AnyObject) {
   navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = 
presenter.addToFavoriteButtonColor()
}
```

this will only work if you have a UINavigationController.